# What is the difference between AJAH and AJAX?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

While reading about ASP.NET Ajax toolkit I stumbled upon the term AJAH. What is it and how is it different from Ajax?

Comment: Whatever it is, it has not made Wikipedia yet (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajah)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAH is someone's attempt to come up with a new buzzword to mean "Having JavaScript make an HTTP request and get back a blob of HTML instead of a blob of XML".

Since Ajax has been taken to mean "Having JavaScript make an HTTP request and get back anything at all" (most often JSON these days, but a blob of HTML is also very common), it is a pretty pointless attempt.

Comment: +1, best to stick to the term AJAX.  Might get a bit confusing if we change the last letter of the acronym for whatever data type we're returning.

Answer (score 3):

Quote taken from [here](http://jimmyzimmerman.com/blog/2006/08/ajax-vs-ajah.html).

> With true AJAX, a call is made to the
>   server, the nicely formatted data is
>   returned and the client application
>   extracts the data from the xml, and
>   replaces whatever elements need to be
>   replaced on a page. With AJAH, a glob
>   of html is returned and slapped into
>   the page.

So basically, *AJAH* returns pure HTML, *AJAX* returns formatted data, such as JSON that is dealt with with by the client scripts.

Personally, I think this just looks like a term only a few developers have used. It's definitely not mainstream.